# How come new object's members are not uninitialized with std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, c++17

Despite the default values of X, Y and Z in Position, when it is initialized in create() none of these variables seem to have been initialized at all. I can set them and then retrieve them, but the default value is never seen. I've tried initializing them various ways but with no success.

**How do I use std::make_unique to return a unique_ptr of type T with its default values set?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>

class Component
{

public:
    Component() {};
    virtual ~Component() {};
};

class Position : public Component
{
public:
    Position(){};
    float x = 123;
    float y = 321;
    float z = 666;
};

std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<Component>>> components;

template<typename T>
T& get(uint32_t id)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T&>(components[std::type_index(typeid(T))].at(id));
}

template<typename T>
void create(uint32_t id)
{
    components[std::type_index(typeid(T))].emplace(id, std::make_unique<T>());
}

int main()
{

    create<Position>(8);
    std::cout << get<Position>(8).z << std::endl; //Value not initialized
    get<Position>(8).z;
    std::cout << get<Position>(8).z << std::endl; //Still not
    get<Position>(8) = Position();
    std::cout << get<Position>(8).z << std::endl; //Now works, but unwanted creation of temporary Position
    get<Position>(8).z = 42;
    std::cout << get<Position>(8).z << std::endl; //Works
    //New try
    create<Position>(8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings, and fix them.

Comment: If every entry in `components` derives from `Component`, why do you `reinterpret_cast` when you could much more safely `dynamic_cast`? `reinterpret_cast` should always be the last cast you reach for in C++

Comment: In your title, you wrote "not uninitialized". I suspect you meant either "uninitialized" or "not uninitialized". I'd edit it for you, but I'm not sure what would be correct.

Comment: @alterigel You would `reinterpret_cast`, for the exact same reason, that you stated. If you **know**, for certain, that the source, and destination types will be compatible, there's no need to pay the runtime cost, of `dynamic_cast`, for the safety, that will not be used, due to your knowledge, stated above.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius A `reinterpret_cast` won't save you from an invalid down-cast. It also won't protect you from casting completely unrelated types, as we see in OP's mistake. I agree that `reinterpret_cast` can be used correctly if you're certain of what you're doing, but you really should be certain. For example, OP's code doesn't protect against `create<Component>(1); get<Position>(1);`, which would be caught by `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @alter: Due to the fact that the type requested is also used to decide from which unordered_map it returns, which only contains pointers to that type. In theory it should never fail casting, and speed is critical. create<Component>(1) would not be returned by get<Position>(1) and a quick count will resolve to see if Position at 1 exists.

Comment: @eljay: I have normal + effective warnings on, but I get none while compiling this code. Am I missing anything useful?

Comment: @alterigel That's why I emphasized, that if you **know** the types will be compatible - there's no need to pay extra runtime cost. Nowhere did I say, that it needs to be preferred over the `dynamic_cast`, in a general case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I understand my mistake now, and see that `create<Component>(1);` and `get<Position>(1)` are different objects. I also just did some tests and reading and I agree that `reinterpret_cast` is necessary here if you can't afford `dynamic_cast`. Thank you for being insistent and making me think twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your get method. Change it as below and it should resolve the issue.

`return reinterpret_cast<T&>(*(components[std::type_index(typeid(T))].at(id)));`

Your `components[std::type_index(typeid(T))]` returns another map and the `.at()` returns a `std::unique_ptr`. You were originally casting the `unique_ptr` using reinterpret_cast which resulted in undefined behavior.

While we are on the subject, do not use reinterpret_cast for casting across hierarchies. Use `dynamic_cast`. The `dynamic_cast` has a well defined behavior when the casting fails for both references and pointers.

In short, you were doing a `reinterpret_cast<Position&>(uniquePtrToPosition)` which is illegal C++.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't think I would've noticed my mistake on my own, but now it's oh-so clear. I'm using reinterpret_cast because (when it works) the way the components are organized one shouldn't be able to get a casting fail due to the way it is stored.